# highlight exit points from a method

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

Is there any tool / extension or other way of highlighting all the places that a method may exit at:

- thrown exception (at least those thrown by the current method, and not caught by it)
- return statements
- last line of a void method

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try ReSharper's [Navigate to function exits](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/webhelp/Navigation_and_Search__Navigate_from_Here__Function_Exits.html).